# Why are some Steam Market items selling above their lowest listed price?

Tags: steam, steam-community-market

I was revisiting my listed items, and found that some items I had up there for months haven't been sold. Specifically I have a pack of gems since April at 1.15€.

[image: Pack of gems being sold since April 16]

This is not surprising, the current price is around 0.81 (and has been for months) so its mostly normal that I can't sell it right? Well, that's what I thought.

The funny thing is, according to Steam this item has been sold **above** my price multiple times, the most recent was [this week](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/753-Sack%20of%20Gems), where it sold for 1,59€. This is not the first time that this has happened, and not just with this type of item either.

I thought with the new system, you can't buy anything over the cheapest price available even if you wanted to? If that's the case, why are some packs being sold at 1,59 while mine hasn't been sold? Is there something I got wrong?

Comment: For the CVers: " I thought with the new system you can't buy anything over the cheapest price available even if you want to, so why are some packs being sold at 1,59 and mine isnt? " is, imo, not an opinion based question.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, it's just that tons of people sell their gems and your isn't first anymore. Also some people are putting theirs at lower prices.

Comment: I thought the priority of bulling/selling was ordered by price, not by time of addition to the list. That's why I found strange for gems being sold at 1,59€ when there are still cheaper (though older) options.